# Angularjs - How to implement drag and drop column using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I trying to drag and drop the table column using angularjs . I tried with smart-table, ui-sortable. I cannot find the solution to implement it.
any simple example or reference have please guide

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following URL.......

http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested